# Ideal files for search in C

Tags: c, string, search

I want to make a file where I can search for specific strings and get an value when that string is found, like in a table.

Imagine the following:

```
"String1" => "val1"
"String2" => "val2"
"String3" => "val3"
```

I want that if I give to my program the value "String1" it will return "val1"

I know I can simply put it in a txt file and read line by line, but that would take to much time, is there a type of file or a way of make it faster?

Thank you

Comment: Given that the file is text, how else would you expect to read it besides a line at a time?  How do you know it would "take too much time"?

Comment: You need to write some code. Naively it would be  something like this pseudocode: `if x == "String1" return "val1"; else if x == "String2" return "val2"; elseif ....` etc.

Comment: Wait what? So, are you asking how to generate a text file, or search it and are you saying that searching for a string key would be faster than searching for a string?

Comment: I want that if I have a string, I should retrive from the file another string corresponding to the one I searched for... Like if it was done in Mysql, I can search for a parameter and I can get all the information associated with that.

Comment: How long is your file. Is it dozends of lines, hundreds, thousands, millions ? The answer depends on that. What is the context, why do you need this ? The answer also depends on this.

Comment: MIME types, depending on the extension

Comment: If reading line by line is too slow, look at how indexes are used in databases. You can build a simplified version of that.

Comment: What is _too much time_ ?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is pretty much what a database index does.  Those are not ordinarily represented as text files, however.  That's in part because searching such an index efficiently requires random access to the file's contents, at least on a record-by-record basis, and most people's definitions of "text file" is inconsistent with fixed-length records.  Additionally, such a file cannot freely be modified by hand without risk (often likelihood) of breaking it.

You can do something more or less as you describe with a fixed format file in which the keys are maintained in sorted order.  For example, maybe each line is structured as 12 bytes of key followed by 68 bytes of value, with ***significant*** trailing spaces as necessary, followed by "\r\n" line terminators (so that your text files are easily read on Windows, too, without modification of code or data).  With such a file structure you can perform a binary search to lookup keys, which would be much more efficient than a linear search.  Note that I say "bytes" rather than "characters" intentionally -- it makes a difference if you're using a variable-length character encoding such as UTF-8.

There are other, more involved alternatives along similar lines; they require adding additional metadata to the file, and so make the file more difficult for a human to interpret or modify directly.  Some of the simplest of those would enable you to trade shorter data for longer keys on a record by record basis.

Note also that none of this makes any sense if reading the whole file into memory is a viable option.  That would remove any need for a fixed format, as well as yielding faster searches than you can expect from any alternative that requires file I/O to be performed as an integral part of the search process.

Comment: That was my idea in the first place. I want to make a server, and I am looking for the best ways of getting the content type field according to the extension received

Comment: @user7122079, unless you expect your data to be too large for the server process to hold in memory, you will be much better off writing the file in whatever format is convenient for you, and having the server read the whole thing at startup.  Structure the *in-memory* representation for efficient searching.  Only if you have very large data or very little memory should you be considering performing searches against a file on disk.